# Python sorted by string and number

Tags: python, sorting

With this code:

```
for mod_name in sorted(module_dict.keys()):
    print(mod_name)
```

I get this output:

```
Module 1
Module 10
Module 2
Module 3
Module 4
Module 5
Module 6
Module 7
Module 8
Module 9
```

It's not a big deal, but it's just annoying.  I could strip the integers out and rebuild the list, but that seems excessive.  I feel like I should be able to specify a key to sorted that will work with strings that end in numbers.

I tried `key=int` and it threw an error.

Comment: You need to provide a custom sort function that performs _numeric_ comparison instead of _alphabetic_ comparison.

Comment: I can't remember how I found this a while back but I followed this to get the nice sort https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `key` to split the string, parse the integer, and sort on that:

```
key=lambda mod_name: int(mod_name.split()[1])
```

You could also move that out into a full `def`-defined function if you don't find that readable.

Comment: If we take the question literally, "Here are the available modules:" is one of the keys, which does not contain an integer so this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like the natsorted function in the natsort library:

```
from natsort import natsorted

strings = ['Module 1', 'Module 10', 'Module 2']
strings = natsorted(strings)
print(strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom function to parse the keys. The implementation of *key()* here will handle numeric values in any position in the string

Taking the OP literally:

```
from functools import cache

mydict = {f"> Module {n+1}": None for n in range(10)}
mydict["> Here are the available modules:"] = None

def key(s: str) -> tuple:
    t = s.split()
    try:
        n = int(t[-1])
        return *t[:-1], n
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return *t,


for k in sorted(mydict, key=key):
    print(k)
```

**Output:**

```
> Here are the available modules:
> Module 1
> Module 2
> Module 3
> Module 4
> Module 5
> Module 6
> Module 7
> Module 8
> Module 9
> Module 10
```

**Note:**

This is **not** a generic solution. It works specifically for the data shown in OP